# How to put php index variable into the another variable in php?

Tags: php

I have a starttotime function in my php code. I want to put it in the for loop. Normally we put the dynamic index which is attached to the variables. but here I can't. I don't know why? I want to put **variable $i** instead of 1 in the code below.

```
$no_col=10;
for ($i=1; $i <=$no_col ; $i++) {
    $start_year_1 = date ('Y', strtotime(${"start1"}));
    $start_month_1 = date ('m', strtotime(${"start1"}));
}
```

I want to repeat every time from 1 to $no_col like below:

```
$start_year_2 = date ('Y', strtotime(${"start2"}));
$start_month_2 = date ('m', strtotime(${"start2"}));
...
```

Comment: "but here I can't" - what does that mean?

Comment: This is why they invented arrays.

Comment: @Nico I haven't put my code here to make it messy. I just write what do I want.

Comment: "I just write what do I want" - what **exactly** do you want? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: You could have dynamic variable name, but it's better to use an array instead

Answer (score 0):

just use dynamic variables

```php
$no_col=10;
for ($i=1; $i <=$no_col ; $i++) {
    // create the variable names
    $start_col = "start" . $i;
    $start_year_col = "start_year_" . $i;
    $start_month_col = "start_month_" . $i;
    // then use those strings as variables
    $$start_year_col = date ('Y', strtotime($$start_col));
    $$start_month_col = date ('m', strtotime($$start_col));
}
```

Comment: `${"start1"}` needs to be replaced too

Comment: @Dean Thank you so much for sending this But in the last 2 lines start1 also change to start2, start3... startno_col

Comment: @brombeer Excatly.

Comment: @saiedvaygani its been fixed